# If $L \subseteq \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is an abelian, nilpotent Lie algebra is it true that $\{v \in V\setminus \{0 \} : x(v)=0 \forall x \in L \} \neq 0$?

Tags: lie-algebras

I have the following question but I can’t see to find an answer floating about anywhere.

In this setting $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and is nonzero.

If $L \subset \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is abelian and consists only of nilpotent maps, is there some nonzero $v \in V $ such that $x(v)=0$ for all $x \in L$?

**EDIT**

In fact I have just looked and seen that more generally this result is true even without $L$ being abelian but the proof is a bit longer than I would like and I think having this abelian condition should make a short proof. Is this true?

Comment: Going through the same proof works, but that might not be optimal

Answer (score 3):

From [Engel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel%27s_theorem) it follows without the assumption of abelian.

If you don't want to use the theorem (as you said in your edit), you can use the following argument.

Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ a basis of $L$. Define $V_1=\{v\in V:x_1 v=0\}$, this is a non trivial subspace of $V$, now $x_2(V_1)\subseteq V_1$ because if $v\in V_1$ then $x_1(x_2)v=x_2(x_1v)=0$. $x_2$ is still a nilpotent map on $V_1$, and so have a null vector.

The subspace $V_2=\{v\in V_1: x_2 v=0\}$ is invariant under $x_3$ (from the same reasoning using that $x_3$ commute with both $x_1$ and $x_2$) and not trivial. Continuing this argument to get that $$V_n=\{v\in V:\forall i\; x_iv=0\}\neq \{0\}$$
as needed (because the $x_i$ form a basis).

The main point here is that if $A, B$ are commuting linear maps then the subspace of eigenvectors (with a given eigenvalue) of A is B-invariant.

Comment: How does it follow from Engel’s theorem?

Comment: Read the statements part in Wikipedia.  It mention that the theorem is equivalent to the statement about null vectors.

Comment: In step 3 of the proof of that statement on the Wikipedia page, it says let’s $v $ be a nonzero vector in $W$. How do we know that $W$ is nonzero?

Comment: By induction, because $\dim \mathfrak{h}<\dim \mathfrak{g}$